# Loading parquet with large string

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, pyarrow

I am processing (using pyspark) dataframes which can potentially contain large string values.
In simplification the column contains response from the API up which is string of size up to 20 MB.
Usually this string is smaller than 10 MB. I have noticed that when the string size reach certain size - around 16 MB, reading those parquet files is very slow and consumes lot of memory (my spark cluster throws OOM's).Both for spark and pyarrow, however not for pandas (I guess due to cpp implementaion of pyarrow).

Is there any way to make it faster.
Can someone confirm my hypothesis that this is related to memory allocation in java in order to handle large strings?

Below output from parquet-inspect:

```
############ file meta data ############
created_by: parquet-mr version 1.12.2 (build 77e30c8093386ec52c3cfa6c34b7ef3321322c94)
num_columns: 1
num_rows: 100
num_row_groups: 1
format_version: 1.0
serialized_size: 400


############ Columns ############
api_response

############ Column(ocr_response) ############
name: ocr_response
path: ocr_response
max_definition_level: 1
max_repetition_level: 0
physical_type: BYTE_ARRAY
logical_type: String
converted_type (legacy): UTF8
compression: SNAPPY (space_saved: 82%)
```

Comment: @ Mateusz Are you using azure databricks?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula We are running in GCP using data proc server less, and most of data is stored in plain parquets.

Comment: By any chance, have you tried the suggestion given in related [SPARK-4073](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4073), to use  `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=4096m`?

Comment: @mazaneicha Yes it help for memory but still performance is awful. Actually i moved to gzip compression now.